# Moving from point to point using java swings

Tags: java, graphics, awt, swingx

I have created a code for an object to move from point to point. Now i need help with one thing. The condition is that the program should prompt the user for a question and if the user answers it correctly the point should move otherwise the point should not move and it should display the next question, this will go on till all the 10 questions are over. If the user reaches the other end he wins otherwise he loses. here is the code for the dot to move from point to point.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Test();

    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Long startTime;
        private long playTime = 2000;

        private Point startPoint, endPoint;
        private Point pointOnTimeLine;
        private double pointInTime; // For rendering...

        public TestPane() {

            startPoint = new Point(0, 95);
            endPoint = new Point(190, 95);
            pointOnTimeLine = new Point(startPoint);
            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                    if (startTime == null) {

                        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    }
                    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long diff = now - startTime;
                    if (diff >= playTime) {
                        diff = playTime;
                        ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                    }
                    double i = (double) diff / (double) playTime;
                    pointInTime = i;

                    pointOnTimeLine.x = (int) (startPoint.x + ((endPoint.x - startPoint.x) * i));
                    pointOnTimeLine.y = (int) (startPoint.y + ((endPoint.y - startPoint.y) * i));


                    repaint();
                }
            });

            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, 10, 10));
            g2d.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(endPoint.x, endPoint.y, 10, 10));
            g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g2d.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(pointOnTimeLine.x, pointOnTimeLine.y, 10, 10));
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

here is the code i used to get user input

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class input1
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    String str1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("france has how many varieties of cheese ? a: 100 b: 200 c: 250");
if(str1.equals("c"))
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "good job ", "answer", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
else
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "sorry try again ", "answer", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
}
}
```

please help me out . thanks in advance

Comment: You've posted requirements and code but have asked no *specific* question. Please fix this so that we can know how to help you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels these two codes work perfectly. But when i run the program i want the question to appear first and if the user answers it right the dot should move otherwise it should display "sorry.. try again"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class td {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Train Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(new TrainCanvas());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class TrainCanvas extends JComponent {

    private int lastX = 0;

    public TrainCanvas() {
        Thread animationThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
while(true)
{
String str1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("france has how many varieties of cheese ? a: 100 b: 200 c: 250");
if(str1.equals("c"))
{       

                    repaint();
                    try {Thread.sleep(100);} catch (Exception ex) {}  
String str2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("where did noodles originate ? a: India b: Italy c: China");
if(str2.equals("b"))
{       

                    repaint();
                    try {Thread.sleep(100);} catch (Exception ex) {}     
String str3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("which place is famous for good chocolate ? a: switzerland b: Germany c: China");
if(str3.equals("a"))
{       

                    repaint();
                    try {Thread.sleep(100);} catch (Exception ex) {}   
String str4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("what is the staple food of India ? a: rice b: bread c: roti");
if(str4.equals("a"))
{       

                    repaint();
                    try {Thread.sleep(100);} catch (Exception ex) {}   
String str5 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("where did ice cream originate ? a: greenland b: china c: korea");
if(str5.equals("b"))
{       

                    repaint();
                    try {Thread.sleep(100);} catch (Exception ex) {}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "GOOD JOB!!!   LEVEL COMPLETE ", "answer", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 
break;
}
else
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "GAME OVER  (restarting...) ", "answer", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

} 
} 
else
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "GAME OVER  (restarting...) ", "answer", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
}
else
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "GAME OVER  (restarting...) ", "answer", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
}
else
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "GAME OVER  (restarting...)", "answer", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
}
else
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "GAME OVER  (restarting...)", "answer", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}


            }
}
        });

 animationThread.start();

 }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D gg = (Graphics2D) g;

        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();

        int trainW = 100;
        int trainH = 10;
        int trainSpeed = 30;

        int x = lastX + trainSpeed;

        gg.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        gg.fillRect(x, h/2 + trainH, trainW, trainH);

      lastX = x;
    }

}
```

thanks for the help anyway...